# a tag that looks like a button using CSS

Tags: css

I made the following CSS class:

```
.mine-button { 
    outline: 0;
    background-color:rgb(153,153,153);
    margin: 0 4px 100px 0;
    padding: 0 1em;
    color:rgb(255,255,0);
    height: 2em;
    text-decoration: none !important; 
    cursor: pointer; 
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align:middle;
    -moz-border-radius: 15px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 15px;
    float:right;
}
```

Then I added the following to the HTML file:

```
<a class='mine-button'>Read more</a>
```

but this is what I get:
[image: ScreenShot]

There's 2 problems:

1. The "Read me" is not aligned vertically in the middle of the "button"

2. The "button" is over the yellow border of the text although the margin-bottom in the class above is set to 100px !

Comment: I'm not sure if you have control over this, but yellow text on a black background is pretty close to committing a designer hate crime.

Comment: A `a` element is rendered as an inline-block, which means that it will collapse around it's contents. Try using a `div` around your link. Please add the complete html and css for this block.

Comment: `appearance:button;` ...

Comment: a element is inline element

Comment: @Musa Most developers require support for a lot of browsers and `appearance` is not widely supported yet

Comment: margins behave differently when defined on floated elements, read here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4631765/how-come-the-floated-elements-cant-set-their-left-and-right-margins

Comment: @Sumurai8 There's also-webkit appearance http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_appearance.asp

Comment: @metacompactness http://www.w3fools.com/ -- apart from that, I will never use a site that simply refuses to style itself for internet explorer/opera.

Comment: Problem solved, thanks guys I used bottom:30px

Comment: @Sumurai8 how do you write code in the comments like the "a" and "div" you wrote above??

Comment: @MikeRobinson I can change the yellow color but why? which colors should I use with a black bg (3 or 4 colors) other than white?

Comment: @Sumurai8 And I was going to apply for a certification test at w3schools! but it's weird that most books cite them.

Comment: @metacompactness Use backticks (\`).

Comment: To solve the issue of why the margin bottom of 100px doesn't work , please post the html and css for the text block as well.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding:

```
.mine-button {
  position: relative;  
  line-height: 2em;
}
```

Assigning *line-height* the same value as your *height* will make the content vertically align.

The `.mine-button` position problem might come from the parent (height, max-height, etc.) or from the previous element, I guess a `<p>`. Can you provide a complete example for a more accurate answer.
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
line-height:30px;
```

in the css

Answer (score 1):

You are using `height: 2em`, I added `padding-top: 0.3em` and decrease the height to `height: 1.7em` and it makes the text in centre.

Here is the [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fyNpp/).

Add `margin-bottom: 10px` to move it in the yellow line.

Answer (score 1):

Change your a tag to

```
<a class='mine-button'><span>Read more</span></a>
```

and Use 'flexbox' to overcome your improper usage of margin, and vertical alignment issue.

```
.mine-button { 
    outline: 0;
    background-color:rgb(153,153,153);
    display: -webkit-box;      /* OLD - iOS 6-, Safari 3.1-6 */
    display: -moz-box;         /* OLD - Firefox 19- (buggy but mostly 
                                 works) */
    display: -ms-flexbox;      /* TWEENER - IE 10 */
    display: -webkit-flex;     /* NEW - Chrome */
    display:flex;
    align-items:center;
    justify-content :center;
    height:30px;
    width:100px;
    color:rgb(255,255,0);
    text-decoration: none !important; 
    cursor: pointer; 
    -moz-border-radius: 15px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 15px;  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to add

```
display: block;
```

rule

Comment: An element with float, already act like if there was a display: block; on it. That is why it didn't work

Answer (score 0):

try adding `padding-top:5px;` to your css.

Answer (score 0):

This one looks better.Have a look on this: I think the height and the padding was not stable. this should do.

```
.mine-button {
  background-color: rgb(153,153,153); /* Green */
  border: none;
  color:yellow;
  border-radius:15px;
  padding:1em 1em;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
   cursor: pointer; 
  font-size: 16px;
  float :right;
}
```

The second problem, you might want to look on to the `position` tag in CSS and set the `left and right` manually. That what I will do. Maybe there are another modern ways but I just go traditional. Hope this help, cheers!!!