# Colors to use with black background?

Tags: html

Is using yellow text on a black bg bad as Mike pointed out [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17926133/a-tag-that-looks-like-a-button-using-css?noredirect=1#comment26190530_17926133)? If yes what colors should I use (RGB or hex values)?

[image]

Comment: I don't know whether you are color blind or your monitor has a very strange saturation setting. The best color to contrast against black is either white or bright gray.

Comment: It's readable, but rather hideous.  I may be biased, though -- i happen to hate the color yellow just about anywhere it's used.  :P

Comment: Not saying its off topic, because I think its fine, but you might get some creative / interesting answers from http://ux.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1):

Yellow is a bad choice, but using grey intensity values varying from;

RGB: 65 65 65 to RGB: 180 180 180

can solve your problem. Gives a decent, elegant look to the site as well.

Something to try. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

My best color that I can match with the black background in HEX format is `#x5x5x5` where `x` can be `d` to `f` since pure white is not really a good choice for black background especially when the font is too small and pure yellow also hurt the eyes. Use the "creamy" yellow eg: `#edebad`.

Anyway that was just my opinion